# Creating multiple copies of text box in ms word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

I have one textbox in a word document and want to fill that text box with different content for each page.

For example if I write the following list A, B, C then I want word to create 3 pages similar to the current page but the content in the first is A, in the second B then C.

How may I do that? I remember that I did it a long time ago but don't remember how exactly

Comment: "write the following list A, B, C" - where? Did you use VBA "a long time ago"?

Answer (score 0):

### This has never been possible in Word's native commands.

I am not denying that you did it previously, but it was through a macro or Add-In.

You can very simply save such a blank textbox formatted the way you want in your Text Box Gallery. Then insert a new text box as needed. You can even assign a keyboard shortcut to that. Here is [my article on the Microsoft site on how to assign keyboard shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330).